# Sorting alpha numeric values

Tags: mysql

I have a column for house no as shown below.I want sort this values

```html
hsno
----
66
58FF
A51A
A50(1)
A8
A3
D27FF
D27
D28
```

I want to sort this like

```html
hsno
-------

58FF
66
A3
A8
A50(1)
A51A
D27
D27FF
D28
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Could the letter prefix ever be more than one letter?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.35-MariaDB,Letter prefix can be more than one letter@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @Simba how come A51A came before A3..can you explain thay way of sorting?